# How to use a template generated by joomla?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, dreamweaver, wampserver

I will develop a website using  joomla ,mysql,php,wampserver,dreamweaver

All my tools are ready(installed),and I will  run the website on the localhost.

I have used joomla to choose a template, now in this phase I want to change the template to suite my website so I have choose dreamweaver to manage my pages(add my own logo and forms..).

But I don’t know now what to do.

What I have tried:

Create from dreamweaver a new website with the following parameter:

name :test

Http adresse: `http://localhost`

Technologie:php/mysql

File : C:\wamp\www\test\

Now I want to use the template chosen from my website(copy and paste the directory of the website don’t work)

How can I use the template from created website? And can I still manage the website named test from joomla administrator ?

Update

I have installed the template following this link : http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla15/joomla_templates.htm

and I found a component that allow me to add a form : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/4939

but still dont know how to modify the template add logo for example

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, uninstall Dreamweaver and never set eyes on it again.

All you need is wamp and a Joomla package.

**Update:**

If you use Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools and inspect the element, you will see the following code which is located in **template.css** on line 156:

```
#logo {
    float: left;
    height: 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 12px 14px 0;
    width: 320px;
}
```

To add a logo of your choice, you can add something like the following:

```
background: url(http://joomla15.siteground.com/FaceBook.png) no-repeat;
```

So you final code will look like:

```
#logo {
    float: left;
    height: 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 12px 14px 0;
    width: 320px;
    background: url(http://joomla15.siteground.com/FaceBook.png) no-repeat;
}
```

You can obviously change the height and add extra bits if you please.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And always copy the template before modifying it.  As long as you are on Joomla 2.5 or 3 you can copy the template in the template manager.

Comment: @Julie - Ok I have seen you update. What do you mean by add a logo? Do you mean replace a current one or add a module position and logo from scratch? I'm not sure what template you have used but may I suggest using a professional and free one, such as the [Master Theme by Yootheme](http://www.yootheme.com/themes)

Comment: @Lodder I have used this one http://www.siteground.com/template-preview/joomla_15/siteground-j15-86 and I want to add my logo in the top (the blue area)